# SELECT JOIN in same table ON multiple rows

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a table with an itemID and a categoryID columns. Both columns are primary keys because each item can have more than 1 category:

```
itemID  |  catID
-----------------
1        |  2
1        |  3
1        |  4
2        |  2
2        |  3
2        |  4
```

I want to select items with the same categories (based on all the item categories, not just one) so I need to kind of JOIN the same table.

I want to be able to find itemIDs with the same catIDs based on a specified itemID.

**Note:**  For example item 1 have categories 2,3,4,5,6 and item 2 have categories 2,3,4,5,6 and item 3 have categories 3,5,6 then if i compare item 1 to item 2 and 3 i need to get item 2 first and then item 3 because item 2 have more categories matches than item 3.. Obviously it need to be done with all the items not only 3.. This way I can recommend visitors of similar products...

Comment: Please provide an example not only of the data and the table structure but also of the expected result.

Comment: @VolkerK: I don't think the expected result can be drawn as a table. The expected result is to get itemIDs with the same catIDs. So I can do a SELECT itemIDs thath have same catIDs as a specified itemID..

Comment: If the result can't be drawn as a table, then there's no SQL in the world that'll produce it.  That's one of the tenets of SQL is that the resultsets are themselves tables.  Perhaps you should break down your process into being able to find all items that belong to a particular set of categories, and calling that for all possible combinations of categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Bill's initial query, this ought to order it in descending order by the number of categories matched (since the join should return one row per match). I also excluded the item being queried on from the result.

```
SELECT c2.itemID
FROM categories c1
JOIN categories c2 ON c1.catID = c2.catID
WHERE c1.itemID = :id
AND c2.itemID <> :id
GROUP BY c2.itemID
ORDER BY count(c2.itemID) DESC;
```

Comment: Number of categories won't do.  The categories have to be the same.

Comment: Of course it will only return items with the same categories :) I was talking about the number of categories only in reference to the subsequent ordering.

Comment: Looks like its doing what I want! Thanks.

@siride: You only say like 'Number of categories won't do' and 'If the result can't be drawn as a table, then there's no SQL'. Just post a correct answer if you have it. It will help more...

Comment: What if I need to order the list by categories matched and also by highest vote taken from another table? The table 'votes' contain two columns: 'itemID' and 'total_value', 'total_value' being the final rate. Can you post the updated code separately? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So you want to choose one itemID, then match it to all other itemID's that share one or more catID's?

```
SELECT DISTINCT c2.itemID
FROM categories c1
JOIN categories c2 ON c1.catID = c2.catID
WHERE c1.itemID = ?
```

Comment: Something like that, but ORDERED by items that have the most categories matches. For example item 1 have categories 2,3,4,5,6 and item 2 have categories 2,3,4,5,6 and item 3 have categories 3,5,6 then if i compare item 1 to item 2 and 3 i need to get item 2 first and then item 3 because item 2 have more categories matches than item 3.. Obviously it need to be done with all the items not only 3.. This way I can recommend visitors of similar products...

Comment: @Jonathan: please edit this "little" amendment into your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You have many to many relation, so the query will look like:

```
SELECT item.name 
  FROM item AS b 
   JOIN itemcategories AS ab ON b.ID = ab.itemID 
 where ab.catID =2;
```

Comment: I dont think its correct. I want to be able to find itemIDs with the same catIDs based on a specified itemID. Based on all the categories of the item, not just in one.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to select items with the same categories (based on all the item categories, not just one) so I need to kind of JOIN the same table.

Without mentioning anything else about the output, you can do something like:

```
Select C.itemid
From categories As C
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From categories As C2
                Where C2.catID = C.catID
                    And C2.itemID <> C.itemID
                )
   And C.itemID = ?
Group By C.itemid
```

(From comments)

> Something like that, but ORDERED by items that have the most categories matches. For example item 1 have categories 2,3,4,5,6 and item 2 have categories 2,3,4,5,6 and item 3 have categories 3,5,6 then if i compare item 1 to item 2 and 3 i need to get item 2 first and then item 3 because item 2 have more categories matches than item 3

This adds a different complexion to the question and is why you should include expected output in your original post. Taking what you have written literally:

```
Select C.itemid, Group_Concat(C.catID Order By C.catID ) As Categories
    , Count(*) As MatchCount
From categories As C
    Join categories As C2
        On C2.itemID <> C.itemID
            And C2.catID = C.catID
Group By C.itemID
Order By Count(*) Desc
```

Comment: Well, the second code you posted is wrong. First of all is C and not C1. And second and most important I restarted the server after running the code because apache something went wrong and everything just went slow. Chrome stopped working and Apache went Off.

Comment: @Jonathan - I can't speak to your setup however, I have corrected the typos. I'm assuming that the categories table has an index on both itemId and catId? Group_Concat can be an expensive operation but then you also did not mention how many rows are involved nor even whether you actually wanted a concatenated list. We are all guessing as to what you actually seek.

Comment: Well I think that if I need to compare all the tables items is something like 6000+ items.. What do you think is the best way to do it?

Comment: @Jonathan - Firstly, if you filter for a single itemID, does the query return the correct result? If it does, then we are talking about ways of making it more efficient.