# SQL/PHP: Order by highest vote from different table

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I needed to recommend to the visitor similar items to the one they where looking at. So I asked in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378743/select-join-in-same-table-on-multiple-rows/) for a SQL query to get items with the same categories (from a 'categories' table). The next is the correct code I'm actually using:

```
SELECT c2.itemID
FROM categories c1
JOIN categories c2 ON c1.catID = c2.catID
WHERE c1.itemID = :id
AND c2.itemID <> :id
GROUP BY c2.itemID
ORDER BY count(c2.itemID) DESC;
```

It returns items ordered by the number of categories matches (from a table containing 'itemIDs' and 'catIDs'). So for example: item 1 have categories 2,3,4,5,6 and item 2 have categories 2,3,4,5,6 and item 3 have categories 3,5,6 then if I compare item 1 (the one the visitor is looking at) to item 2 and 3 I need to get item 2 first and then item 3 because item 2 have more categories matches than item 3.

**NOW**: I need also to to order the results by highest vote. The items votes are in a different table. The table 'votes' contain two columns: 'itemID' and 'total_value', 'total_value' being the final rate.

So, How to order the results also by the number of categories matches and also by highest vote from a different table???

**Update**: The number if items in the table is 8000+. I think the better thing to do to recommend the most similar items is to order it first by items with the exact set of categories and then by votes. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Which is the primary ordering criteria, the count or the vote? And does the `votes` table contain one row per 'itemID' or multiple rows  per 'itemID' and you want to only look at the highest? As with your previous question supplying example data would help.

Comment: The votes table contain only one row per 'itemID'.
I think order criteria need to be categories first and then votes but I'm not sure. Can you post both options? I need to do some test to check witch order criteria is better for item recommendation.. What do you think?

Comment: Please read update: I think the better thing to do to recommend the most similar items is to order it first by items with the exact set of categories and then by votes. Need to update all the code in this case I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c2.itemID
FROM categories c1
JOIN categories c2 ON c1.catID = c2.catID
JOIN votes v ON v.itemID=c1.itemId
WHERE c1.itemID = :id
AND c2.itemID <> :id
GROUP BY c2.itemID
ORDER BY count(c2.itemID), v.total_value DESC;
```

Comment: I'm getting results not ordered by the highest rate.. I mean, I have for example an item with a rate of 6 in place number 2 and a item with a rate of 6.2 in place number 3.. and then in place number 4 an item with rate 5.9

Comment: then switch the count(c2.itemId) and v.total_value
ORDER BY v.total_value,count(c2.itemID) DESC;